# Need different inventory and currency, should I make two websites or stores?

Tags: magento2, inventory, multi-website

So here is my issue. We are running a clothing store which ships internationally as well. Often we need to maintain different inventory for our local and international customers. For local store, shipping address has to be limited to Pakistan while billing address can be anywhere in the world. And for the international store, the shipping address can be any country except Pakistan whereas the billing address can be anywhere in the world. Furthermore, we also need the Pakistan store to have PKR currency while the international store to have a couple of major currencies (USD, GBP, EUR).

What's the best way to achieve this? Should I make two websites or two stores? We are using Magento 2.2.

Furthermore, I would like two show the store selector (i.e. Pakistan or International) first time a user visits the website (something like this: https://www.kayseria.com/country.php?20180219155425) and then it should always show their selected store to them. Unless they want to change it (there will be an option for that in the header).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the scenario in a cryptic manner, **you must need to go with the multi-website concept not multi-store**.

> **In Magento 2 - Currency scope is either Website Level or Global level**
>   **so if you want to achieve multi currency feature you need to create**
>   **multiple website. Because we only have one Base currency for one site.**

Second thing if you go with store level then you can only do currency switcher on different store but order should be go in base currency only.

> **Regarding that country part you really need to use GEO IP based store**
>   **switcher which is works same like you asked , it will take country**
>   **based on customer 's ip address and if they want to change then they**
>   **can change it for the same .**

**Below is the extension link for GEO IP Based store locator :**

https://www.magedelight.com/geoip-advance-magento-2.html

https://amasty.com/geoip-redirect-for-magento-2.html

Hope this help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. You didnt touch on the inventory part. Should the multi website concept also let me handle different inventories for same products?

As for the currency, I dont want the order to go in different currencies. Its fine if the orders actually end up being in base currency.

Lastly, the extension you mentioned. They seemed to be for multi-store configurations. Or they can also be used for different stores that are under separate websites?

Comment: for extension - yes it worked for both. Regarding inventory  yes i forgot to mention that - for inventory you only have option is extension , because magento 2 native either with store or site do not provide multi inventory concept so whatever you take multi inventory will not achieve. for that you only have option is multi warehouse extension

Comment: Thank you @ManthanDave for detailed explanation between multi-store and multi wesbite.